# How can we determine if user has navigated to the default page directly?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, uri, trailing-slash

We know that we can find our scripts and parametres by using php's `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]`.

My problem with this is that querying the default script (page) with `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` will always return the full script. Both `https://www.apple.com/index.html` and `https://www.apple.com/` will return `index.html`.

**If a user has landed on the default page** (`https://www.apple.com/`), **then is there a way that we may query the URI and have either** `/` **or**  (NULL) **returned?**

(As a background to this question, what I am *ultimately* trying to do is clean up indexing duplicate errors from Google, specifically.)

Server model is LAMP (CentOS 6), if this helps.

Comment: You could do this with .htaccess and mod-rewrite. It's not something I'd handle with PHP

Comment: Working on raw $_SERVER is very unclear. You should definitely give a try to https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard What I am reading from your comment is: "…something that we **can't do with php.**" Sadly, I suspected this as well. Do you have any thoughts on an `.htaccess` solution?

Comment: Added mod-rewrite-related tags.